# First entry of node is null

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "1": { "name": "Hauptbahnhof Berlin", "city": "Berlin"}, "2": { "name": "Hackerscher Markt", "city": "Berlin"}, "3": { "name": "Hauptbahnhof Frankfurt", "city": "Frankfurt"} }' 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com/stations.json'
```

results in

[image]

which looks exported like:

```
{
  "stations" : [ null, {
    "city" : "Berlin",
    "name" : "Hauptbahnhof Berlin"
  }, {
    "city" : "Berlin",
    "name" : "Hackerscher Markt"
  }, {
    "city" : "Frankfurt",
    "name" : "Hauptbahnhof Frankfurt"
  } ]
}
```

Selecting the data has a null value now, why so?

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference stationsRef = database.getReference("stations");
        stationsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<Map<String, String>> value = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

> => Value is: [null, {name=Hauptbahnhof Berlin, city=Berlin}, {name=Hackerscher Markt, city=Berlin}, {name=Hauptbahnhof Frankfurt,
>   city=Frankfurt}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase automatically adds index 0 as a null value, if not passed. So changing the insert to

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "0": { "name": "Hauptbahnhof Berlin", "city": "Berlin"}, "1": { "name": "Hackerscher Markt", "city": "Berlin"}, "2": { "name": "Hauptbahnhof Frankfurt", "city": "Frankfurt"} }' 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com/stations.json'
```

fixes the problem.